# After "Go to Definition", is there a command to return to where you came from?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

If so, is it a stack?
That is, can I:
GoToDefinition
GoTODefinition
GoToDefinition

and then pop back up the call stack?
None of the Edit.GoTo... commands do what I am looking for.
TIA.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can go to the last place you navigated to by doing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>

(That's the control key and the "minus" or "dash" key.)

Comment: and yes, you can drill down and then drill up again

Comment: You can often also use your back and forward mouse buttons to do the same (at least I'm pretty sure mine were bound by default).

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am looking for.
Unfortunately, it breaks down when "Go to Definition" takes you to a xaml file; then, View.NavigateBackward does nothing.  
Interestingly, after using "Go to Definition", when I try to use View.NavigateBackward in the Command window, I get the message that the command is not available.

Comment: You should mention CTRL+Shift+- to go forward. Very useful.

Comment: View.NavigateBackward (Ctrl+-) is not the best command for the purpose. For example, if you invoke Edit.GoToDefinition (F12) and then click a few times with the mouse moving the cursor around, all those moves are recorder in the navigation stack. Contrary, if you use **View.ForwardBrowseContext** and **View.PopBrowseContext** commands, you will be redirected _directly_ to the previous definition (the place that you invoked Edit.GoToDefinition (F12) last).

Comment: @BorislavIvanov Yes for me it decreases the font :( gonna have to remap it

Answer (score 13):

The correct way to navigate this stack is with **View.ForwardBrowseContext** and **View.PopBrowseContext** commands. In the default C# schema they are bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> respectively.

Answer (score 11):

Tip by Brian Sullivan (Ctrl+-) works great.

You also can use a side button on your mouse (if your mouse has a side button and that button programmed for Back functionality in a browser).

Answer (score 3):

If you have an MS mouse with the latest Intellipoint drivers installed, you can have program-specific commands associated with mouse buttons. Find out what the "Back" keyboard command is for your program. For VS .NET 2003/2005/2008 it is Ctrl+\  (control backslash) which is tied to View.NavigateBackward. Then go into the Control Panel for the mouse, click on the checkbox for "Enable program-specific settings" and then click on Settings.

Click on "Add" and pick your favorite Visual Studio and map Ctrl-\ to the left button.

Others programs of interest:

```
uVision3 IDE (the Keil compiler):    Alt-Left
Adobe Reader 9.0:                    Alt-Left
javaw (as in Eclipse):               Ctrl-F2
VB6:                                 Ctrl-Shift-F2
```

Actually, the Eclipse one isn't Ctrl-F2 but is something that cannot be mapped, so I added that mapping within Eclipse and then the new mapping in the mouse driver.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Although it's quite tedious to setup this up --- i.e., it's not on by default.  This is so bloody awesome.  I wish I could up-vote you more!

Answer (score 2):

In Microsoft Dev Studio it was always mapped to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> (The <kbd>*</kbd> on the numerical keypad) but not in C# Express, I notice. Here it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>, as already noted.

Answer (score 2):

`Navigate backward` and `Navigate forward` is the right choice. These can be found in toolbars.

Comment: Actually I could find them in the "View" menu.

Comment: Works on mac. In year 2019, Android Studio, there are Back and Forward items in Navigate Menu.

Answer (score 0):

A third party tool like ReSharper would give you the functionality you require.

It is "da bomb!"

Navigation in the Solution explorer is a thing of the past.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: Not in the budget, and it doesn't play well with ViEmu.
Great product, though.

Comment: FWIW, I'm using ReSharper alongside ViEmu, and they seem to be getting along fine. The developer of ViEmu takes special care to make sure it works with R#, since he knows that lots of people are using it.

Comment: So what is the resharper keyboard shortcut that results in a View.PopBrowseContext ?

Answer (score 0):

I just use the back button on my mouse.

Has always worked by default for me.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for me to do it is to add a bookmark before I go to the definition. To get back i just toggle back