# Is there a keyboard shortcut to go forward in Visual Studios?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studios when traversing code you can click on a symbol and `right-click "Go To Definition"`. The result is that you can see the definition of the symbol. Then you can return to the symbol by using keyboard shortcut `ctrl+-`. (For more info see [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877873/after-go-to-definition-is-there-a-command-to-return-to-where-you-came-from).)

Is there a way to go forward? How?

I find this to be a useful feature in other IDEs so I figured Visual Studios would have it and I just don't know how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> will navigate forward.

You can configure keyboard bindings in Tools -> Options, then Under "General" the "Keyboard" section.  The two commands you are referring to are `View.NavigateBackward` and `View.NavigateForward`