# Visual Studio 2015: Ctrl+Shift+8 (View.PopBrowseContext) to navigate back not working?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2015

A keyboard shortcut that I've used frequently going back several Visual Studio versions is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to go back to where I was, after doing a <kbd>F12</kbd> to Go To Definition.

In Visual Studio 2015, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> doesn't seem to do anything.

Opening up Visual Studio 2013 and looking at the Tools | Customize | Keyboard dialog, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> is mapped to the command View.PopBrowseContext.  In Visual Studio 2015, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> has that same command mapping, but the command doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to get the View.PopBrowseContext command to navigate back after doing a Go To Definition (<kbd>F12</kbd>) in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Any update on this situation? It's been a year, is there still no fix for this broken VS2015 feature?

Comment: @RonC Latest update is at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/14496

Comment: @JonSchneider Thank you for the link, it's great to see that there is now a roslyn issue for this on github.  I added comments to it as a voice of support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A workaround in Visual Studio 2015 is to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> instead (mapped to the View.NavigateBackward command) to go back after a <kbd>F12</kbd> press, instead of trying to use View.PopBrowseContext / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>.  ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/877876/12484))

Comment: Thanks for this - was stuck using VS2013!

Answer (score 9):

Visual Studio 2015 Connect -> [View.PopBrowseContext command and others doesn't work](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2011983/view-popbrowsecontext-command-and-others-doesnt-work) (*issue removed from Connect site by Microsoft*)

Issue on GitHub -> [Bring back Go to Definition Navigation Stack #14496](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/14496)

**View.NavigateBackward** (Ctrl+-) is not good replacement for **View.PopBrowseContext** (Ctrl+Shift+8). If you invoke **Edit.GoToDefinition** (F12) and then click a few times with the mouse moving the cursor around, all those moves are recorder in the navigation stack.

**View.PopBrowseContext** (Ctrl+Shift+8) redirects directly to the previous definition (the place that you invoked **Edit.GoToDefinition** (F12) last).

- View.PopBrowseContext
- Edit.GoToReference
- View.BrowseNext
- View.BrowsePrevious
- Edit.GoToDeclaration
- View.ForwardBrowseContext

Note: these commands were broken in Visual Studio 2015. Still do not work in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: I also totally agree.  I'm limping along with View.NavigateBackward (Ctrl +-) but it's not nearly as efficient as View.PopBrowseContext.  I often have to use View.NavigateBackward (Ctrl +-)  three or four times before I'm back to the place I hit F12.  

With View.PopBroweContext (Ctl + shift + 8) in prior versions of Visual Studio I only had to hit the keyboard combination ONCE and I was back to the place I used the F12.  I sure how this gets fixed soon in Visual Studio 2015.  It's a real productivity drain to not have View.PopBroweContext (Ctl + shift + 8) working.

Comment: Discussion at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/94907/vs2017-the-command-viewpopbrowsecontext-with-the-k.html.

Answer (score 3):

When you first start Visual Studio, it offers you a choice of typical usage (not sure how it's called exactly): C++, C#, etc. I believe the initial keyboard binding depends on that choice.

I used [FeinCtrl](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2c3354bd-8efd-4ea7-9099-a5fd80ca4185) and noticed that `View.PopBrowseContext` is mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num *</kbd>, and it works just fine. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> is mapped to `Edit.ViewWhiteSpace` for me...

Do you by chance have a conflict, when another command in a different scope is papped to the same shortcut keys?

Comment: Good thought, but I don't think I have a conflict: In the keyboard options dialog, if I focus the "Press shortcut keys" field and press Ctrl+Shift+8, the only item that appears in the "Shortcut currently used by" field is "View.PopBrowseContext (Ctrl+Shift+8 (Global))".

Comment: @Jon Schneider - That dialog checks one scope at a time. The shortcut could be defined, for example, in `Text Editor` scope, and cause a run-time conflict. Do you mind to try that FeinCtrl extension from the visualstudiogallery I referenced above? I wonder if it will find that conflict.

Comment: Nice extension! I gave it a try, but it does look like View.PopBrowseContext is the only mapping for Ctrl+Shift+8 for me: http://i.imgur.com/yfP56lZ.png

Comment: One more test, please: after you use <kbd>F12</kbd>, could you open a Command Window and type `View.PopBrowseContext` in it? Do you get to the previous point? Also, not sure if that matters, but what language are you using? C++? C#? Anything fancy?

Comment: Interesting! The command window returns the error "Command "View.PopBrowseContext" is not available."  This is in a C# project.

Comment: I guess, they decided that you don't need two commands performing the same action. On a positive note, you can re-bind your favorite `Ctrl+Shift+8` to View.NavigateBackward